# Jquery Liquid Slider controls not working

Tags: jquery, navigation, slider, controls, liquid

I'm using the liquid slider found here: http://liquidslider.com/ on this page: http://www.emmaroche.ie/category/2013/

The slider works as expected with one problem: the controls don't work. The code for the controls is:

```
    <div class="controls outside span5 offset7">
        <a href="#left" data-liquidslider-ref="slider-id" class="rslides_nav rslides1_nav prev"><span id="slider-prev"></span></a>
        <a href="#right" data-liquidslider-ref="slider-id" class="rslides_nav rslides1_nav next"><span id="slider-next"></span></a>
    </div>
```

With the important part being the 'data-liquidslider-ref' obviously.

I'm getting the error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'on'' on the page which I presume is to do with the slider loading another (unnecessary) version of jQuery on top of Wordpress's version. But with auto slide turned on the slider works fine so I don't think this is the problem.

The code in the head is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function(){
      $('#slider-id').liquidSlider({

          autoHeight: true,
          autoSlide: false,
          slideEaseFunction: 'easeOutSine',
          dynamicArrows: false,
          slideEaseDuration: 550,
          crossLinks: true,
          autoSlideControls: true,
          autoSlideStartText: 'asas',
          autoSlideStopText: 'asad'

      });
    });
});
```

I've used this slider many times before without a problem and with the same settings.

Kind of stumped as to what the problem might be. I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your page my quick suspicion is on the jQuery library that you are loading:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6'></script>`

Perhaps version 1.4 doesn't have `.on` (I remember jQuery used to have`.live` instead of `.on`)

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the jquery version, which fixed the error it was throwing, but not the problem. Still no response from the controls.

Comment: So the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'on'` is gone? Is there any new errors being thrown at your console?

Comment: Update: That actually had fixed the problem. I just forgot to change back one of the slider options I'd fiddled with before when in 'just-try-everything' mode. Thanks for your help!